# String literal union types fail to compile when created during a map operation

Tags: typescript

String literal union types are failing when we use `map` but not when we directly create an array.

Here is a [Fiddle from the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Unit%20%3D%20'g'%20%7C%20'ml'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Measurement%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unit%3A%20Unit%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Thing%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20measurements%3A%20Measurement%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20things%3A%20Thing%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20measurements%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unit%3A%20'g'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20thingsToo%3A%20Thing%5B%5D%20%3D%20Array.from(%7B%20length%3A%205%20%7D).map((i)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20measurements%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unit%3A%20'g'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D))%3B%0D%0A).

```
type Unit = 'g' | 'ml';

class Measurement { 
    unit: Unit;
}

class Thing { 
    measurements: Measurement[];
}

// works
const things: Thing[] = [{
    measurements: [{
        unit: 'g'
    }]
}];

// fails
const thingsToo: Thing[] = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((i) => ({
    measurements: [{
        unit: 'g'
    }]
}));
```

Errors:

```
Type '{ measurements: { unit: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Thing[]'.
  Type '{ measurements: { unit: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Thing'.
    Types of property 'measurements' are incompatible.
      Type '{ unit: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Measurement[]'.
        Type '{ unit: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Measurement'.
          Types of property 'unit' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Unit'.
```

Why does this happen during a `map`? How can we prevent it?

One approach is to cast as `Measurement`. It isn't clear though why that is necessary and it is also more verbose than not casting, so we would rather not use a cast, unless that's the only way.

```
// works
const thingsToo: Thing[] = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((i) => ({
    measurements: [{
        unit: 'g'
    } as Measurement]
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's explained here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8131)

> The way string literal types work is that a string literal expression
>   must be contextually typed by a string literal type (or a union
>   containing a string literal type) in order to type check as a string
>   literal type instead of as string.

In your code, `'g'` string literal type is widened to `string` because there is no context that would preserve it as literal in `Array...map` expression.

Another workaround is to add explicit return type for `map` callback:

```
type Unit = 'g' | 'ml';

class Measurement { 
    unit: Unit;
}

class Thing { 
    measurements: Measurement[];
}

// works
const things: Thing[] = [{
    measurements: [{
        unit: 'g'
    }]
}];

// works
const thingsToo: Thing[] = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((i): Thing => ({
    measurements: [{
        unit: 'g'
    }]
}));
```